# C++ How to Increment Int Variable From String Array Element

Tags: arrays, string, visual-c++, element, c-strings

I'm wondering if there is a way to increment an int variable when a specific string array element is called? I'm working on a project for fun and have run into a roadblock. The goal of my project is to have a program that determines what genres of electronic music the user likes. The program will present two DJ's and ask the user which one they prefer or allow them to select neither. Each DJ will have up to three genres that they mainly specialize in, and I have created int variables for each (with all being set to 0). Once a user selects a DJ, I want points to be assigned to each genre variable in which the DJ is associated with. I'm unsure of how to set up this rule as everything I have attempted so far has failed (two example attempts are commented out in the code). Eventually my plan is to develop logic to have the DJ's randomly selected, however I need to have the genre tally allocation set up first. Is there any way this can be done? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

```
###include "stdafx.h"
###include < iostream>
###include < iomanip>
###include < string>
###include < array>
###using namespace std;



int main()
{
    cout << "Hello! This program is designed to figure out what Electronic Music you like based on artists presented and the answers you choose...\n" << endl;
    cout << "When you are ready to begin press \"Enter\"..." << endl;
    getchar();


int bigRoom = 0;
int deepHouse = 0;
int drumBass = 0;
int dubstep = 0;
int electroHouse = 0;
int futureHouse = 0;
int hardDance = 0;
int house = 0;
int progressiveHouse = 0;
int techno = 0;
int trance = 0;
int trap = 0;

string textArray[5]{ "DeadMau5", "Armin Van Buuren", "Avicii", "Ferry Corsten", "Kaskade"};
string answer;
    cout << "Select the DJ you prefer by number. Otherwise select 3 if you don't know them. " << endl; //Haven't coded option 3 yet.
    cout << "1 - " << textArray[1] << endl;
    cout << "2 - " << textArray[2] << endl;

    cin >> answer;


    /*
    if (textArray[1]) {
        ++trance;
    }

    for (textArray[1]) {
        ++trance;
    }
    */

if (answer == "1") {
    cout << "You have selected: " << textArray[1] << endl;
}

else if (answer == "2") {
    cout << "You have selected: " << textArray[2] << endl;
}


//cout << trance << endl;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increment each tally once the user has selected a DJ:

```
if (answer == "1") {
    cout << "You have selected: " << textArray[1] << endl;
    ++trance;
    // ++ ohter genres you want to increment
}

else if (answer == "2") {
    cout << "You have selected: " << textArray[2] << endl;
    ++trance;
    // ++ ohter genres you want to increment
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response StaticBeagle. Now my only concern is my goal is to have the textArray element be randomized, so I'm not going to necessarily know which genre to add to. I also want the "answer" to remain 1 and 2. I realize if I were to make "answer" a unique ID such as x1,x2... for each DJ, that may work but I want it to be simple for the user.